# Errors Uploading/Managing large files with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, fs

I'm trying to upload a large PDF file using node.js. So far I can successfully upload the files but once they are uploaded the PDF file has some data missing. Its losing some data during uploaded. The PDF file contains text and images.

Some of the images are missing and some text is also missing. Im using the code below:

```
    var busboy = require('connect-busboy');

    app.post('/upload',function(req, res) {

    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
    console.log("Uploading: " + filename); 
    fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/files/' + filename);

    file.pipe(fstream);

    fstream.on('close', function () {

    });
 });
 });
```

**Also please note I am testing the file upload through Google Chrome POSTMAN extension.**

Below is an image of the error, as you can see the images in the PDF  file are distorted.

[image]

Whats a good way of uploading large PDF files with node.js?

**Update:**

After trying this the error still remains:

```
app.use(busboy({immediate: true }));
```

Comment: Are you using the `immediate` option when initializing busboy?

Comment: @cdbajorin thanks for the comment. No I am using `immediate` actually. will give that a try now and update you.

Comment: @cdbajorin please see updated question. thank you.

Comment: I was actually going to say NOT to use immediate. It starts to read from the request before you are ready to read from busboy, potentially losing some data. Can you post more of the (**relevant**) code? As it stands, you're missing closing braces/parentheses, and you've misspelled the variable `fstream` in `file.pipe(stream)`. If those were fixed, the code would work perfectly fine, so the error is elsewhere.

Comment: @cdbajorin Again thank you for the comment. I have updated my code in the question.

Comment: [this code](https://gist.github.com/cdbajorin/bc302b1334bd17d578c5) works perfectly fine with a [100mb pdf](http://scholar.princeton.edu/angelab/publications/super-Large-Pdf-100Mb) using postman form-data. It's almost a straight copy-paste from your code, all I added was a response message.

Comment: @cdbajorin hmm thats weird, but thank you so much for all the help. I'll look through code in detail and see if I made an error somewhere else. Again thank you.

Comment: @cdbajorin Its weird, I just copy pasted your gist code in and it worked perfectly. No idea why. If you post that as an answer I can accept it and close off the question.